# Showing the description for the term identified by the argument in the Taxonomy Term view

Tags: 7, views

I have a view that is a clone of the Taxonomy Terms default view, it has the depth modifier turned on.  I would like to provide the description field for the taxonomy that has been loaded in the header if it exists.  I'm using this with pathauto, so while the actual url may be something like /pub/by/geo-area/ethiopia, views gets the tid (lets say 3046) as the argument.

How can I then put the description field from that taxonomy term into the header of the view?  I tried creating a relationship for the taxonomy term content, but since I don't know at the time of creating the view what vocabulary the term will be from, and because it is possible that there will be multiple terms for that vocabulary attached to some of the nodes, that doesn't seem to be workable.

I considered an attachment, but I'm not sure how I could pull that off either.  Can I do this without an extra module?

Comment: `but since I don't know at the time of creating the view what vocabulary the term will be from` when you add the relationship, just check all of them :-)

Comment: Yes but I don't want the description for all terms associated with the node via any field at all, I want the description for the term coming in via the contextual filter argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want the description for the term coming in via the contextual
>   filter argument

Ok then,

1) Create a new view

- **Show:** Taxonomy Terms.
- ☑ Create a Block

  - **Display format:** Unformated list **of** Fields

2) Save and Continue.

- Add the Contextual Filter.
- Add the description field.

3) Go back to your other view and attach view to header.

Comment: Oh ok, I knew you could attach displays I don't think I knew you could attach separate views. That'll be great if it works. I won't be able to check it for a bit but I'll look as soon as I can. Thanks!

Comment: @UltraBob, yes, attaching separate views is allowed, no prob.